# Laravel 4: Upload large csv using LOAD DATA INFILE without blank rows

Tags: php, mysql, csv, laravel-4

When I use the next code to upload a large file in mi database I have extra empty rows. If I upload 5000 lines I finally have 5500 lines. The extra lines are in blank. ¿How Can I avoid this?

```
if (Input::hasFile('file_pld')){

$csv = Input::file('file_pld');

$query = sprintf("LOAD DATA INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE usuariospld FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' IGNORE 0 LINES (`CODCENTRAL`, `PLAZO_PP`, `CUOTA_PP`)", addslashes($csv));

return DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec($query);

}
```

Comment: hi ..did your issue solved?? if yes can u plz share how you solved it??

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the csv. You need to clean all the other fields aftaer your last row. Select all with shitf + end + (->, <-, ..
)